# How the number and the lengths of the TLS records affects the TCP packets?

Tags: ssl, tcp

I have an application which uses TLS to exchange data over a TCP connection. If I make all of the TLS connections have the same  number of records and the same length, would this means that the corresponding TCP connections will also have the same number of packets and the same size?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. You don't have any control over how TCP divides payloads into segments, or how IP divides packets into fragments. There is no guarantee that says one write to TCP equals one segment, packet, fragment. It can do anything it likes from sending one byte per packet upwards.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What you mentioned  means that we will not get the same number of TCP packets but it doesn't mean that the total size of the of the all TCP payloads will be different.. Can we then conclude that the number of the TCP packets might be different but the total size of the TCP packets payloads will be equal to the size of the TLS record?!